# R-regex: match strings not beginning with a pattern

Tags: regex, r, regex-negation

I'd like to use regex to see if a string does not begin with a certain pattern. While I can use: `[^` to blacklist certain characters, I can't figure out how to blacklist a pattern.

```
> grepl("^[^abc].+$", "foo")
[1] TRUE
> grepl("^[^abc].+$", "afoo")
[1] FALSE
```

I'd like to do something like `grepl("^[^(abc)].+$", "afoo")` and get `TRUE`, i.e. to match if the string does not start with `abc` sequence.

Note that I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word), and I also tried using `perl = TRUE`, but with no success:

```
> grepl("^((?!hede).)*$", "hede", perl = TRUE)
[1] FALSE
> grepl("^((?!hede).)*$", "foohede", perl = TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you match strings that _do_ begin with the pattern, then negate the logical result from `grepl`?

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to put some more stuff in there! =)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yeah. Put the zero width lookahead /outside/ the other parens. That should give you this:

```
> grepl("^(?!hede).*$", "hede", perl = TRUE)
[1] FALSE
> grepl("^(?!hede).*$", "foohede", perl = TRUE)
[1] TRUE
```

which I think is what you want.

Alternately if you want to capture the entire string, `^(?!hede)(.*)$` and `^((?!hede).*)$` are both equivalent and acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

There is now (years later) another possibility with the `stringr` package.

```r
library(stringr)

str_detect("dsadsf", "^abc", negate = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE

str_detect("abcff", "^abc", negate = TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck on the following special case, so I thought I would share...

### What if there are multiple instances of the regular expression, but you still only want the first segment?

Apparently you can turn off the implicit greediness of the search
with specific [perl wildcard modifiers](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_16.htm)

Suppose the string I wanted to process was

```
myExampleString = paste0(c(letters[1:13], "_", letters[14:26], "__",
                           LETTERS[1:13], "_", LETTERS[14:26], "__",
                           "laksjdl", "_", "lakdjlfalsjdf"),
                         collapse = "")
myExampleString
```

> "abcdefghijklm_nopqrstuvwxyz__ABCDEFGHIJKLM_NOPQRSTUVWXYZ__laksjdl_lakdjlfalsjd"

and that I wanted only the first segment before the first `"__"`.
I cannot simply search on `"_"`, because single-underscore is
an allowable non-delimiter in this example string.

The following doesn't work. It instead gives me the first *and* second segments because of the default greediness (but not third, because of the forward-look).

```
gsub("^(.+(?=__)).*$", "\\1", myExampleString, perl = TRUE)
```

> "abcdefghijklm_nopqrstuvwxyz__ABCDEFGHIJKLM_NOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

But this does work

```
gsub("^(.+?(?=__)).*$", "\\1", myExampleString, perl = TRUE)
```

> "abcdefghijklm_nopqrstuvwxyz"

The difference is the greedy-modifier `"?"` after the wildcard `".+"`
in the (perl) regular expression.