# Regular expression to match string ending with letter but NOT ending with a phrase in R

Tags: regex, r, inverse-match

I need to use `grep` to find all strings ending with `G` but NOT ending with `STIG` or `VÄG` in the following character vector:

```
test=c("EWASPG","AVOPW","SDAGSTIG","ASDVVÄG","ASDVWE","QSCIUVG","QWSFNJG")
```

I tried this but it returns false for any string with the letters `S`, `T` , `I`, `V`, `Ä` preceding the `G` instead of returning false when the `G` is preceded by the exact phrase.

```
grep("[^((STI)|(VÄ))]G$", test, value=T)

# [1] "EWASPG"  "QWSFNJG"
```

Thanks!

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438173/r-regex-match-strings-not-beginning-with-a-pattern).

Answer (score 4):

A [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) always matches a single character, so `[^(STI)]` would match any character except `(`, `S`, `T`, `I` or `)`.

You can use a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that the string doesn't end in a certain substring, but you need to enable Perl-compatible regex mode in R:

```
grep("(?<!STI|VÄ)G$", test, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE);
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/cA8yV5).

Comment: In R, this would then be `grep('(?<!STI|VÄ)G$', test, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! R seems to work fine with Tim's code without needing jbaums extra ' .

Comment: Not sure which extra quote you're referring to. Unless you're just referring to my single quotes in general, in which case they're completely exchangeable with double quotes in this situation.