# Extracting data from vector according to a rule in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the names of the countries which don't start with either "C" or "B" from this vector.

`vec <- c("Colombia", "Chile", "Brazil", "Ecuador", "Peru", "Mexico")`

This works for C or B only:

```
vec[substring(vec,1,1) != 'C']
```

I am trying to combine both cases but this doesn't work

```
vec[(substring(vec,1,1) != 'C') | (substring(vec,1,1) != 'P')]
```

How can I combine both conditions in just one statement?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&` instead of `|`? `vec[(substring(vec,1,1) != 'C') & (substring(vec,1,1) != 'P')]`

Comment: Something using regular expressions would be neater though. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438173/r-regex-match-strings-not-beginning-with-a-pattern) for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this what you are looking for?

```
vec[!substring(vec, 1, 1) %in% c("B", "C")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
vec[grep("^[^CP]",vec)]
```

Comment: You can also use `value = TRUE` so you don't even have to subset: `grep('^[^CP]', vec, value = TRUE)`